# Alpha From PNGs Butchered

Tags: xna, antialiasing, monogame

I have a pretty vanilla Monogame game. I'm using PNG for all my sprites (made in Photoshop). I noticed that XNA is butchering the aliasing; no matter what I do, my graphics appear jaggedy.

Below is a screenshot. The bottom half is what XNA shows me when I zoom in 2X using a `Matrix` on my `GraphicsDevice` (to make the effect more obvious). The top is when I pasted the same sprites from Photoshop and scaled them to 200%.

Note that partially transparent pixels are turning whiteish.

Is there a way to fix this? What am I doing wrong?

Here's the relevant call to draw to the `SpriteBatch`:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(this.texture, this.positionVector, null, Color.White, this.Angle, this.originVector, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
```

(`this.positionVector` can easily be `Vector.Zero`; `Color.White` as 100% alpha, I think; `this.Angle` can be a real angle (small `>` in the image) or zero (the orb itself).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you're enabling blending in your `SpriteBatch.Begin()` call.  I think for PNGs, `BlendState.NonPremultiplied` is probably the one you want.

Comment: Its depends if the file is being loaded though the content processor or not. If it is BlendState.AphaBlend is the one he wants as by default the processor will pre-multiplies the alpha for you irregardless of the file type.

Comment: Please see my related question about how to add content. I'm not currently using the XNA content pipeline.

Comment: @ashes999 Well, you'll need to use the right blend mode for however you're getting the image into your engine.

Comment: @NathanReed `NonPreMulitplied` for the win. Is it possible you can also attempt to answer my other question? :) http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/44599/the-right-way-to-add-images-to-monogame-windows